# Analogue of the SublimeCodeIntel supports java/c/c++

Tags: sublimetext2

Is there any analogue of the SublimeCodeIntel, who supports java/c/c++?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a combination of [exuberant-ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) and the [ctags for Sublime plugin](https://github.com/SublimeText/CTags)